# Einstein tensor in 2d

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

Is the Einstein tensor in 2D or 1+1D always zero? If so, why?
I recently installed EinsteinPy and started playing wing different metrics - for the 2D cases the result turned out to be always zero.

Comment: Einstein tensor in 2D is always zero. You can just compute it explicitly (for a generic metric) and verify this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Einstein's field equations in (1+1) spacetime?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773866/226902), see e.g. references in the linked answer.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1417/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Special_cases). From here you will learn that in 2D

$$R_{abcd} = \frac{R}{2}(g_{ac}g_{bd}-g_{ad}g_{cb})$$
Contracting $a$ and $c$ both sides, you will obtain
$$R_{bd} = \frac{R}{2}g_{bd} \implies G_{bd} = 0$$